# How to get audio input from usb microphone with C# and NAudio

Tags: c#, .net, usb, wav, naudio

I'm trying to get audio input from Usb device using NAudio. 
I'm using WavIn class but like this:

```
NAudio.Wave.WaveIn input = new NAudio.Wave.WaveIn();
input.DeviceNumber=0;
```

But I don't know how to get device number of my micro.
I know about this method:

```
WaveIn.GetCapabilities();
```

But there is no my micro, becouse it is not recognized as micrphone.
Also I can get my usb device like thi:

```
    System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Select * From Win32_USBHub");
    var devices = searcher.Get();
    foreach(var d in devices)
    {
        var deviceId = (string)d.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID");
        var pnpDeviceID = (string)d.GetPropertyValue("PNPDeviceID");
        var description = (string)d.GetPropertyValue("Description");
    }
```

But I can't pass it to WaveIn.

How can I get usb device input using NAudio?

Answer (score 2):

Well if you want to record from it with `WaveIn` you need it to appear in the list of available `WaveIn` devices:

```
for (int n = 0; n < WaveIn.DeviceCount; n++)
{
    var caps = WaveIn.GetCapabilities(n);
    Console.WriteLine($"{n}: {caps.ProductName} {caps.Channels}");
}
```

Alternatively, it may be accessible with `WasapiCapture`:

```
var deviceEnum = new MMDeviceEnumerator();

foreach (var device in deviceEnum.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Capture, DeviceState.Active))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{device.ID}: {device.DeviceFriendlyName} / {device.FriendlyName}");
}
```